# Password Validation with preg + PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

To avoid SQL injection, I would like to do a password validation, what's the best way, not to write quotes or the equal sign?
Do I need to block writing single or double quotes and the equal sign? ( ' ' = ) '1=1' etc...

```
function safePass($value = null){
    if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/', $value)) {
        return $value;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Exemple:
$pass = Pass@123 ---- Correct

$pass = Pass@a'1=1' ---- Invalid, contains quotes and equals sign

Comment: Why do you need to validate the password to prevent SQL injection? You're going to hash the password, so the original password won't be in the SQL. Also you should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection in general.

Comment: No, don't do this. You should pretty much never modify users passwords. Prepare your statements and parameterize your queries instead.

Comment: would that be ideal? $VerifyPass = password_verify(strip_tags($_POST['pass']));

Comment: No. Do not strip, escape, trim, encode, sanitize, or otherwise molest the password. Feed it to the password functions as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you goal is only to prevent SQL injection the best option is to use **PDOStatement** like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->execute([$email]);
```

That would fix this types of vulnerabilities, without and additional validation.

Comment: I'm already using Pdo, it was just for extra security, but I understand from the comments posted earlier, it's better to use hash

Comment: would that be ideal? $VerifyPass = password_verify(strip_tags($_POST['pass']));